# Using setText for more strings

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an Android app. This is my code:

```
FieldSolution.setText("y =","(Double.toString(m))","x + ", "(Double.toString(b))");
```

I'm trying to print "y = mx + b" whereas m and b are doubles. Somehow I'm getting exceptions.

Where lies my mistake?

Comment: You just need a `+` operator (string concatenation) instead of commas between your strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fieldSolution.setText("y =" + Double.toString(m) + " x + " + Double.toString(b));
```

or simply

```
fieldSolution.setText("y =" + m + " x + " + b);
```

Aside: Use [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for variable names

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.format`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
FieldSolution.setText(String.format("y = %fx + %f", m, b));
```

You can use modifiers on the `%f` format specifier to control precision and width of the output. You can also, if appropriate, supply a locale as an argument to `format()`.